# Using HTML anchor link fragment in Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, routes, anchor, hash-location-strategy

I am working with an Angular 6 project in which I have disabled/removed hash-location-strategy which removes # from URL.

due to this change the link having:

```
<li routerLinkActive="active">
   <a [routerLink]="['/settings']">Contact Settings</a>
   <ul class="child-link-sub">
      <li>
         <a href="#contactTypes">Contact Types</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

is no more working it just skips the current components URL and puts #contactTypes after localhost.

I found this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6595) which should solve the issue using

```
<a [routerLink]="['/settings/']" fragment="contactTypes" >Contact Types</a>
```

which puts #contactTypes at the end of the URL but it doesn't scroll to the top of the browser.

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6595

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Angular 6.1 comes with an option called [`anchorScrolling`](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#anchorScrolling) that lives in router module's [`ExtraOptions`](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions). As the [`anchorScrolling` definition](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#anchorScrolling) says:

> Configures if the router should scroll to the element when the url has a fragment.
>
> `'disabled'` -- does nothing (default).
>
> `'enabled'` -- scrolls to the element. This option will be the default in the future.
>
> Anchor scrolling does not happen on 'popstate'. Instead, we restore the position that we stored or scroll to the top.

You can use it like that:

```
const routerOptions: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: false,
  anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
  // ...any other options you'd like to use
};

// then just import your RouterModule with these options

RouterModule.forRoot(MY_APP_ROUTES, routerOptions)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. 
What I missed was that you have to use 
routerLink="./" fragment="anchorName"
you can not use href="#anchorName"

Comment: Also, this only works on the first click. Does not work on the 2nd.

Comment: For this to work on the 2nd click, you need to add `onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'` option in the routerOptions.

Comment: This is how it should be implemented.

Comment: To get this solution to work I had to also add  https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#scrollPositionRestoration

Comment: Please note that this answer was based on Angular 6.1 and may not apply to current Angular version and beyond.

Comment: ^^^ Confirmed, this does work in Angular 11 too. All options mentioned above work too, i.e. `anchorScrolling: 'enabled', onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload', scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'`.

Comment: Just wondering, how to make this work on page _load_? `anchorScrolling` doesn't work automatically then, e.g. if I open http://my-ng-app.com/route#section-1 in a new browser directly, it does not take me to "section-1". Probably there should be a setting or manual way of doing this?

Comment: Is there a solution with HashLocationStrategy (useHash)? It's a conflict. I think you can either use one or the other. With useHash you cannot use `<a href="#foo">`, results in 404. It's because the hash feature is already in use by Angular Router (e.g. the URL looks like `http://localhost:4200/#/`). Is there a solution or should I scroll with JavaScript? :( We cannot disable hash routing.

Answer (score 31):

I was looking for a similar solution and  tried to use the [ngx-scroll-to](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to) package and found that its not  working in latest version of angular so decided to look into other option and found that we can use `scrollIntoView`

HTML code :

```
<button (click)="scrollToElement(target)"></button>
<div #target>Your target</div>
```

Ts code :

```
  scrollToElement($element): void {
    console.log($element);
    $element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "nearest"});
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is absolute good and easy to understand with simple and short code

Comment: can you provide for dynamic linking? There are other answers for this purpose but code is not simple

Comment: This is not ideal, because it does not provide the user with a link that they can share with others, such as "example.org/help#installing".

Comment: @ANeves Yes , "This is not ideal"  right now, but that feature `achorScrolling` was not available when i answered the question. since angular 6.1 was released  later .This solution may be helpful for those who work in older version of angular . Its great that solutions are  evolving with every new version of angular

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me (I'm using Angular 12.1.3):

On the HTML template:

```html
<a (click)="scrollTo('anchorId')">Scroll to another position</a>
```

Pass the id of the element you want to scroll to (without the hashtag symbol `#`) to the function.

Then, on Typescript, use  `.scrollIntoView` to make the browser scroll to the position of that element.

```js
scrollTo(element: any): void {
  (document.getElementById(element) as HTMLElement).scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "nearest"});
}
```

Comment: In the HTML template: `<div id="anchorId">`

Comment: also works on v17.0.8

Answer (score 8):

For accessibility reasons I had to a link at the beginning of the document to provide direct access to the content to user using a screen reader, skipping that way parts of the page repeating from page to page.

As I needed the link to stay focusable (preferably keeping the href attribute), as I was actually outside the app-root or any component (still solution works inside a component), to do that I used simple good old fashion html and javascript :

```
<a href="./#content"
     onclick="event.preventDefault(); location.hash='content';"
     class="content-shortcut"
     title="Access page content directly"
     i18n-title
     aria-label="Access page content directly"
     i18n-label>Access page content directly</a>
  <style>
    .content-shortcut {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      height: 0px;
      font-size: 1px;
    }

    .content-shortcut:focus,
    .content-shortcut:active {
      position: relative;
      opacity: 1;
      height: auto;
      font-size: 1em;
      display: block;
      color: black;
      background: white;
    }

  </style>
```

Comment: this is what i have to do as well, thanks for the post

Comment: The best solution for meeting WCAG requirement to skip main navigation.  Very simple and elegant.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**This is for Angular 9, but, I am sure the community will benefit this,**

You can use `Location` in the `@angular/common` to get the current path.

Let's say you have the following element with an id to focus

`<div id="bring-me-to-the-focus">`

I am only showing extracted code blocks here.

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private location: Location) { }

this.location.path() + '#bring-me-to-the-focus';
```

I am sure this will help someone :)

Cheers.

Comment: I don't think this is necessary since router provide this feature with `anchorScrolling` and `onSameUrlNavigation`

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by Nitin Avula in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836497/using-html-anchor-link-id-in-angular-6#comment102332899_52724769), using `routerLink` for a hash anchor only works if you are navigating to a different route or have `onSameUrlNavigation` enabled in your router config.

A way to get round this is to get rid of `routerLink` and instead use `this.router.navigate` in your `*.component.ts` file with the `fragment` parameter:

HTML -

```
<a (click)="scrollToContactTypes()">Contact Types</a>
```

TypeScript -

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }

scrollToContactTypes() {
    this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = "reload";
    this.router.navigate(["/settings"], { fragment: "contactTypes" }).finally(() => {
        this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = "ignore"; // Restore config after navigation completes
    });
}
```

Comment: Interesting answer if you're pretending to allow `onSameUrlNavigation = "reload"` for some reason IDK

Answer (score 2):

use [ngx page scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-page-scroll)

```
 <a pageScroll href="#awesomePart">Take me to the awesomeness</a>
 <h2 id="awesomePart">This is where the awesome happens</h2>
```

Comment: Nice answer, it's working well. If you are in the /home page for example, you need to do href="home#anchor". +1

Comment: You do not need a library for that, this behavior is included in the angular router.

Comment: @Machado yes you are right we just need to add `  anchorScrolling: 'enabled'`  in app routing module inside ExtraOptions for `forRoot`

Answer (score -1):

You need to use hash routing strategy to enable the hash scrolling.

you need to give second argument as an object like RouterModule.forRoot([],**{useHash:true}**}. It will work.

Comment: hash strategy deals with hashes as routes, isn't it so?