# Angular router issue when using css anchor

Tags: css, angular, angular-routing

I want to use css anchor in my html page.
And below is my code:

`<a href="#test"></a>`

`<div id="test" name="test">123</div>`

But I will get this issue.
[image: angular router issue]

Actually, I don't want angular router works.

Comment: You just need to add `target="_self"` to your anchor tag and it will work as expected.

Comment: @ObsidianAge not a duplicate since the OP's question is about Angular 2+ and the above link is about Angularjs (Angular 1.x)

Comment: Thank you @ObsidianAge , I checked that question.Option 1 can solve my problem. but add `target="_self"` doesn't works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docs reference: [Angular Routing Navigation](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/navigation/)

A work around for this could be

Option 1: Using fragments

In your HTML file

```
<a [routerLink]="['/']" fragment="test"></a>
```

In your Typescript file

```
 ngOnInit() {
     this.route.fragment.subscribe(fragment => { this.fragment = fragment; });
    }

    ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
      try {
          if(this.fragment) {
              document.querySelector('#' + this.fragment).scrollIntoView();
          }
      } catch (e) { }
    }
```

Option 2 : Just create method and scroll

In your HTML file

```
<button (click)="scroll(test)"></button>
<div #test >Your target</div>
```

In your .ts file

```
scroll(el) {
    el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth"});
}
```

Angular 6.1 and above also has an option called **anchorScrolling** but as far as I'm aware, it's still in beta

Reference to  [how to use anchorScrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836497/using-anchor-link-id-in-angular-6)

Comment: Thank you @Richard Pariath, Option 2 solve my problem. But I am not sure about option1. what `this.route` means? I have tried angular Route and Router. but still the error "fragment doesn't exist"