# Anchor in the same page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Im creating an ionic app based on Angular (first time)
I created a card with anchors that send me to other cards in the same page.

```
 <ion-card>
          <ion-item  class="activated">
            <ion-icon name="camera" slot="start"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label  routerLink= "#visit">Pics</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
 </ion-card>
```

This anchor should send me to a card with the same id="visit" but it's not working .

```
<ion-card id="visit">
      <ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-title > 
          <ion-icon style="padding-top:5px" name="camera" ></ion-icon>
            Pictures
          </ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-header>
  </ion-card>
```

I checked google but all result that I get are about other issues.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836497/using-html-anchor-link-id-in-angular-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The`routerLink` attribute is how Angular transite into pages, to connect to an anchor in your own page, use the old and cool `<a href=#visit>`

```html
  <ion-card>
    <ion-item  class="activated">
      <ion-icon name="camera" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        <a href="#visit">
          <ion-label>Pics</ion-label>
        </a>
      </ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>
```

Another solution, to makes scroll smooth you can call an method on click at `<ion-label (click)="scroll()">Pics</ion-label>` and invoke

```
 scroll() {
   var anchor = document.getElementById("visit");
   anchor.scrollIntoView({block: "end", behavior: "smooth"});
 }
```

Comment: I tried   <a href="#visit">
            <ion-label (click)="scroll(visit)" >Pics</ion-label>
          </a>
and function on mypage.ts
scroll(id){
    var anchor = document.getElementById(id);
    anchor.scrollIntoView({block: "end", behavior: "smooth"});
  }

But It didn't work

Comment: At click function, pass argument as string 'visit'. If you made this in function, is not necessary pass href. <a href=..> is an alternative solution.

Comment: Ok thanks your function worked you don't need  the link <a href >...
just put the function on the label (click)="scroll()"
Please delete the first part so I can close it as the answer

Comment: A tip if you want to use this in other parts of this project, is extract this code to an scrollService class. I`m happy to contribute !