# Pages gets reloaded when the href attribute contains '#'

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In my app-routing.modules.ts I have the following script:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {SearchComponent} from './search/search/search.component';
import {RegisterComponent} from './register/register.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The HTML of my LoginComponent contains `<a href="#">Top</a>`. If the user clicks on that link, he will be redirected to the root page. I have also tried it with `<a href="login/#">Top</a>` but the same page will be reloaded.

What is the reason for that? I just want the user to jump on the top of the page.

Comment: Try this <a href="/login">

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/52724769/7291317.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a section that contains the top of your page with an ID like this:

```
<section id="top">
    <h1>Introduction</h1>
    <p>Top of the page </p>
</section>
```

Then in your link, you have to call the ID :

```
<a href="#top">Top</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I have used `/` after `login` (like `login/#`). My solution was using `href="login#"`. I still don't understand why I need to add `login`, since it is the same page but that works.

Answer (score 0):

From Angular 6.1, You can pass `extraOptions` to your `RouterModule.forRoot()` as a second parameter and can specify `scrollPositionRestoration: enabled` to tell Angular to scroll to the top whenever the route changes.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled', // Add options right here
    })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

[Angular Official Docs](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions)

Comment: I have tried that but it will still redirect to the root page.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of # use href="javascript:void". this should work

Comment: instead of href = "#" use href = "javascript:void" in angular