# include anchor links or add multiple url in (event.url) at angular2+

Tags: angular, typescript, anchor, router

It works fine though on regular links - `/press/media`, but not with anchor links - `/press/media#152`. how will I include both regular and anchor links or add multiple url with the existing code below?

in app.component.ts

```
 this.router.events
    .subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.headerFooter = (event.url !== '/press/media')
      }
    });
```

hope someone can help me.

Comment: Hey there, this question already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52724769/9983888). Hope this helps

Comment: hey just checked that, it s not the answer im lookin for.