# How to use HTML anchor link #id inside dialog (MatDialog) in angular 10

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to implement navigation within a pop-up/dialog. The tradition way of using [anchor link #id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836497/using-html-anchor-link-id-in-angular-6) isn't working for me because for `#test` it is opening `localhost:4200/#test` and my content is not available there as it's a pop-up.

What is the way to provide anchor #id linking within a dialog?

Comment: Please provide the code to reproduce the issue

Comment: Here is [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-h4zdgz?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) if this helps